# Cannot access a value in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access `bc_product.eng_name` in the following code but it's not working. The foreign key of the `bc_product` table is in `bc_invoice_product` table. Can someone point me in the right direction?

View

```
def invoice_pdf(request, inv_no):

    inv = BC_Invoice.objects.select_related().get(invoice_no=inv_no)
    return render_to_pdf('bc_invoice_pdf.html', {'pagesize': 'A4',
                                                  'inv': inv})
```

Template

```
{% for item in inv.bc_invoice_product_set.all %}
    <tr>
        <td align=center>{{ item.unit_quantity }}</td>
        <td align=center>{{ item.bc_product.eng_name }}</td>
        <td align=center>{{ item.unit_price }}</td>
        <td align=center>{{ item.unit_amount }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE:**

Model

```
class BC_Product(models.Model):
    ............
    eng_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BC_Invoice(models.Model):
    ............    
    product = models.ManyToManyField(BC_Product, through='BC_Invoice_Product')

class BC_Invoice_Product(models.Model):
    ............
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(BC_Invoice)
    product = models.ForeignKey(BC_Product)
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that `inv.bc_invoice_product_set.all` returns `BC_Invoice_Product` models and in this case you should use `{{ item.product.eng_name }}`.

From your models it is visible that foreign key relationship fied to`BC_Product` in `BC_Invoice_Product` is `product` and not `bc_product`.

Also, [convention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships) is to have ForeignKey field named as a model name, lowercased - that would probably make it much easier to follow relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to look the value up outside the view? Fire of the development server, stick:

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

In after `inv = ...`

And explore the query API a bit in the console to see if it matches your expectations. What you've got should work.